# How to align properly?

Tags: css, angularjs

I have to align the fields(right) as shown in below image.Here is my code built in Angularjs using label tag for all the legends in form and i styled using CSS. How to correct the alignment, so that i can submit this to higher officials?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<head>
<title> SAP WORKBENCH </title>
<style>
 body{
 background-color: lightgray;
 margin-left: 500px
 }
 .option{
 width: 300px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 4px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 .button{
 width: 300px;
 }
</style>
</head>
 <h2>Password Reset</h2>
 <body>
  <div ng-app="">
   <b></b>
   <form>
    <label>System:</label>
     <select class="option" ng-model="myVar">
      <option></option>
      <option value = "DR9">DR9</option>
      <option value = "QR9">QR9</option>
      <option value = "PR3">PR3</option>
     </select>
    <br><br>
    <div ng-switch="myVar">
      <label>Client:</label>
      <select class="option" ng-switch-when="DR9">
       <option>100</option>
       <option>400</option>
       <option>500</option>  
      </select>
      <select class="option" ng-switch-when="QR9">
       <option>500</option>
      </select>
      <select class="option" ng-switch-when="PR3">
       <option>500</option>
      </select>
      <select class="option" ng-switch-default>
       <option></option> 
      </select>
     </div>
    <br>
    <label>User:</label> 
    <input class="option" type="text" placeholder="Enter User Id.."></input>
    <br><br>
    <label>New Password:</label>
    <input class="option" type="password"></input>
    <br><br>
    <label>Re-Enter New Password:</label>
    <input class="option" type="password"></input>
    <br><br>
    <input class="button" type="button" value="Reset">
   </form>
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: ?? 500px margin on body, why ? . label can be resized via width and display and text-align reset too, button can have a margin left equal to the size of labels . `body {
  background-color: lightgray;
  /*margin-left: 500px*/
}

.option {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
label {
display:inline-block;
width:200px;
text-align:right;
}

.button {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left:205px;
}`  no need to update structure nore use grid or flex here. the old way is fine unless you need more flexibility

Comment: Please see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: Hi wen,thanks for the inputs.also, have you seen the image i attached.Please go through it and help accordingly

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each label + select into a separate div. Then give the parent container the properties `display: flex, flex-direction: column, align-items: center`.

Further tip: Try to avoid the `<br >` tags and work with `margin-bottom`. For this purpose also the new single `<div>` elements can be used.

Answer (score -1):

It would be best if you use bootstrap to do this. It's much easier to get alignment done that way so please do use bootstrap. Also I have done a test code without bootstrap using `display: flex;`. Hope this helps your problem (I have not included any of your ngswitch statements here)

HTML

```
<h2>Password Reset</h2>

<body>
  <div>
    <b></b>
    <form class="d-flex flex-row">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column text-right mr-1">
        <label class="margin-b">System:</label>
        <label class="margin-b-7">Client:</label>
        <label class="margin-b-7">User:</label>
        <label class="margin-b-7">New Password:</label>
        <label class="margin-b">Re-Enter New Password:</label>    
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="margin-b">
          <select class="option" ng-model="myVar">
            <option></option>
            <option value = "DR9">DR9</option>
            <option value = "QR9">QR9</option>
            <option value = "PR3">PR3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-b">
          <select class="option">
            <option>100</option>
            <option>400</option>
            <option>500</option>        
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-b">
          <input class="option" type="text" placeholder="Enter User Id.."></input>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-b">
          <input class="option" type="password"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-b">
          <input class="option" type="password"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-b">
          <input class="button" type="button" value="Reset">
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.option {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button {
  width: 300px;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.mr-1 {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.margin-b {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.margin-b-7 {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

JS Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/SJ_KIllshot/mhp6uksd/

Comment: You are using his HTML which is invalid.